# Does Don Quijote in fact say "Facts are the enemy of truth"?

Tags: quote-source, spanish-language, don-quixote, miguel-de-cervantes

I recall a quote of the sort "Facts are the enemy of truth" attributed to Miguel de Cervantes in his book *Don Quijote de la Mancha*. However, I could not find the quote in the book by searching for "truth" or "enemy". There are also some sources on the web claiming the quote, such as [here](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/9269790-facts-my-dear-sancho-are-the-enemy-of-truth), [here](https://www.quora.com/How-true-is-the-quote-facts-are-the-enemy-of-truth-from-Don-Quixote), or [here](https://www.uh.edu/engines/epi1025.htm).

Is there an actual passage in the book which conveys the meaning of the above quote? Or is this a total misattribution?

Answer (score 25):

As the OP noted, this quote does not appear in *Don Quijote de la Mancha* by Cervantes. It does, however, appear in a different version of *Quijote*: the musical based on Cervantes' work, with libretto by Dale Wassermann entitled *[The Man of La Mancha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_of_La_Mancha)*. When the Don is being questioned by Dr Carrasco the following dialogue occurs:

> Dr Carrasco: There are no giants. No kings under enchantment. No
> chivalry, No knights. There have been no knights for three hundred
> years.
>
> Don Quixote: So learned - yet so misinformed.
>
> Dr Carrasco: These are facts.
>
> Don Quixote: **Facts are the enemy of truth**.

Comment: How prescient -- he anticipated Colbert's "truthiness" and Conway's "alternative facts".

Comment: @Barmar or... "truthiness" is a lot older than we think they are.